# Store Enum into Cassandra as Integer using Spark Cassandra Connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to store a scala Enumeration in Cassandra using its Int representation, but I always get a com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException. I wonder whether the Enumeration class is a special case, or I am doing something wrong.

Edit (2015-12-16).
Let me try to extend my question with a code snippet, so I can probably convey the idea better.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import com.datastax.spark.connector._

object WeekDay {
  sealed abstract class WeekDay(val id: Int)

  case object MON extends WeekDay(0)
  case object TUE extends WeekDay(1)
  case object WED extends WeekDay(2)
  case object THU extends WeekDay(3)
  case object FRI extends WeekDay(4)
  case object SAT extends WeekDay(5)
  case object SUN extends WeekDay(6)

  val values = Map(0 -> MON, 1 -> TUE, 2 -> WED, 3 -> THU, 4 -> FRI, 5 -> SAT, 6 -> SUN)
}
import WeekDay._

object Example {

  case class MyCassandraRow(id: String, weight: Int, day: WeekDay)

  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("cassandra-connector-example")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
      .setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val data = sc.parallelize(
      Seq(
        MyCassandraRow("identifier1", 10, MON),
        MyCassandraRow("identifier2", 20, FRI),
        MyCassandraRow("identifier3", 1, SUN)
      )
    )

    data.saveToCassandra("db", "custom_data")
  }
}
```

This code works alright if I create my custom_data table using TEXT for the "day" field, but fails if I set as INT with the following stacktrace:

```
com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object FRI of type class WeekDay$FRI$ to java.lang.Integer.
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(TypeConverter.scala:42)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(TypeConverter.scala:40)
at scala.PartialFunction$AndThen.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:185)
```

So, I have tried to implement the TypeConverter as described at https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/6_advanced_mapper.md
as follow:

```
implicit object IntToWeekDayConverter extends TypeConverter[WeekDay] {
  def targetTypeTag = typeTag[WeekDay]
  def convertPF = {
    case i: Int => values.getOrElse(i, MON)
  }
}

implicit object WeekDayToIntConverter extends TypeConverter[Int] {
  def targetTypeTag = typeTag[Int]
  def convertPF = {
    case d: WeekDay => d.id
  }
}
```

But I still get the same error.

I have published the whole scala file here: https://gist.github.com/davideanastasia/b0bef569b4b7dec66c3f#file-cassandraenum-scala

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic converter from Enum -> Integer in the Spark Cassandra Connector. I would just map that column with `.id` to get the integer representation.

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
import WeekDay._
val meetingDays = Seq(WeekDay.Mon, WeekDay.Wed)
//meetingDays: Seq[WeekDay.Value] = List(Mon, Wed)
meetingDays.map(_.id)
//Seq[Int] = List(0, 2)
```

Comment: I will then need a temporary class to convert in and out from Cassandra into my case classes. I thought I could leverage the TypeConverter in the Spark Cassandra Connector to do the heavy lifting for me. Thanks for your answer anyway, I have extended my question, so probably the context is a bit more clear.

Comment: Have you tried converting to java.lang.Integer instead of the scala one

Comment: Yes, that works! I had to change a few minor things after that, but that made it work. If you take the time to write a full answer, I will upvote it.